# exception in java, string index out of range: -1

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to remove the last character on my output but this error shows me, `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOx4n.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRXoC.png)

Comment: it means `output` length is zero, means `rs` is empty so the while loop does not execute

Comment: [Post code as text in your question, not as an image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1831987)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of output before the split, the error is maybe the string length is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code is trying to accomplish, however it's likely what is happening is output is empty, and you're trying to access the -1th character for it, which can't be done.

To fix what you've done, try and implement the following.

On line 59, update the if statement to read:

```
if (rs.next() == false && output.ToString() != "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to *remove* the last character in the `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`, you do it like this:

```
if (output.length() > 0) {
    output.setLength(output.length() - 1);
}
```

PS: I downvoted you because you are not supposed to copy your code into the post, not upload it as a screenshot.